# PHP file get contents hangs - why timeout doesnt work and how to fix

Tags: php, apache, file-get-contents

I have a few servers that fetch images from other sites.
After working for months. Apache started crashing every few hours.  (see config at the bottom of the post)

Investigation using logging in the code, shows that sometimes file_get_contents hangs keeping the apache process in W state forever. Sample URL of fetched file that hanged:  https://www.mxstore.com.au/assets/thumb/3104041-c.jpg

I have set timeouts in 3 locations and still the Apache process hangs forever

```
set_time_limit (10);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout',10);
```

And also in the context (see timeout=>3) :

```
$opts = array( 'http'=>array('header'=>" User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0" ,'timeout'=>3 ) );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data=  file_get_contents($product[p_img], false, $context,-1,1500000);
```

How can I either make timeout work and/or understand why the image is not fetched?

Config:
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Apache API Version  20120211

Comment: have you tried using `CURL`? It may allow you more control.

Comment: I need to make it work since its an existing solution. Moving to curl means many tests that I'd like to avoid by understanding/solving the problem

Comment: Setting the timeout might not work unless its allowed in the pho.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately all my searches didnt yield a solution. I implemented Curl for the calls.